# Error when trying to use to "Insert into" a ms-access database

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to insert data into an access database and this solution has worked for me in the past, but this time I keep getting the error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Here is the code & below it is the database in access:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class NewFS_Templates_Centured_Template
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub sub_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
        'form data requests----------------------------------------------------

        Dim strFirst As String = first.Text
        Dim strLast As String = last.Text
        Dim strStatusg As String = statusg.Text

        Dim strPhone As String = phone.Text
        Dim strEmail As String = email.Text
        Dim strCat As String = cat.Text

        Dim strJoint As String = joint.Text
        Dim strAdvise As String = advisor.Text
        Dim strAuth As String = authors.Text

        Dim StrAtt As String = attend.Text
        Dim strTitle As String = title.Text
        Dim strAbs As String = abstract.Text

        'Open Db Connection (Remember to include Imports System.Data.OleDb)
        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim dbconn As OleDbConnection = Nothing

        dbconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("..\App_Data\ResearchSymposiumReg.mdb"))
        dbconn.Open()

        'SQL actions 
        'INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country) VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO ResearchSymposium2014 (AuthorLast, AuthorFirst, RegStatus, Email, Phone, Catagory, JointSubmission, Advisor, Co-Authors, Attending, PosterTitle, Abstract) values (@strFirst,@strLast,@strStatusg,@strPhone,@strEmail,@strCat,@strJoint,@strAdvise,@strAuth,@StrAtt,@strTitle,@strAbs);"
        Dim objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbconn)

        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AuthorLast", strFirst))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@AuthorFirst", strLast))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@RegStatus", strStatusg))

        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Email", strEmail))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Phone", strPhone))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Catagory", strCat))

        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@JointSubmission", strJoint))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Advisor", strAdvise))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Co-Authors", strAuth))

        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Attending", StrAtt))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@PosterTitle", strTitle))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Abstract", strAbs))

        'Sets each parameter to "DBNULL" or "blank" if they are null/blank
        'objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@FirsNtame", If(strFirst, DBNull.Value)))
        For Each param As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter In objcmd.Parameters
            If param.Value Is Nothing Then
                param.Value = DBNull.Value
            End If
        Next

        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'Close DB Connection
        dbconn.Close()
        Server.Transfer("ThankYou.aspx", True)
    End Sub


End Class
```

[image: This is the access database in design mode]

Comment: Doesn't OLEDB use "?" for parameter placeholders, and not "@param"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Actually both will work, but `?` is generally preferred because OleDb **ignores** the actual parameter *names* and only pays attention to the *order* in which they appear in the CommandText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field name `Co-Authors` contains a hyphen and therefore must be enclosed in square brackets, i.e.,

```
... Advisor, [Co-Authors], Attending, ...
```